# How to trigger AJAX from a search button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have the following Javascript:

```
<script>
function showtickets(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/processes/editticket.php?WTNum=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

It works perfectly if I use a selectbox and trigger the function with "onchange". However, my client requested a searchbox instead. I cannot get it to work with a search box. Here is my HTML for the search box and the div where the results should go.

```
    <form class='form-horizontal col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12' name="editticket" method="post" action="/processes/updateticket.php">
   <div class='panel panel-primary'>
        <div class='panel-heading'>
            <h3 class='panel-title'>Edit Work Tickets</h3>
        </div>

            <div class='panel-body'>
                <div class="input-group">

    <span class="input-group-addon">Enter Ticket #</span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" name="WTNum" >
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="showtickets(document.getElementById('search').value)">Search</button>
                            </span>

                 <div id="txtHint"><b></b></div>

</form>
```

Am I missing something!! This is driving me INSANE!!
Thank you all in advance. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: any error hit when u open in debug mode?

Comment: You tagged this with jQuery, can you use jQuery? If so, this is a fairly simple problem that can be solved by [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) or any number of 3rd party plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just call the `showtickets` function without arguments and then inside the function you do this

```
str = document.getElementById('search').value;
```

Comment: Yea didn't notice OP had the type set to button which stops it from acting like a submit button.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must you javascript debug or alert in some scope to find where error